# Outlook-web-app is not importing events from my generated icalendar

Tags: php, laravel, outlook, icalendar, outlook-web-app

For my application I use `laravel 5.3` and a package called `markuspoerschke/iCal` which you can find [here](https://github.com/markuspoerschke/iCal).

When a student wants to subscribe to his or her calender, we generate an URL which can be filled into Google Calender and Outlook. Except the last mentioned `outlook` it isn't importing any events.

Example of how our generated ICS looks like. This contains 1 event with the description of 'test'.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR 
VERSION:2.0 
PRODID:www.onderwijsonline.nl 
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT15M 
BEGIN:VEVENT 
UID:58e5f21fc2551 
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20170406T090000 
SEQUENCE:0 
TRANSP:OPAQUE DTEND;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20170406T140000 URL:http://oo.dev/calendar/event/420 
SUMMARY:Test 
CLASS:PUBLIC 
DTSTAMP:20170406T094535Z 
END:VEVENT 
END:VCALENDAR
```

The script that calls the package to generate this:

```
public function getIcal($token = null)
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->getByToken($token);

        $vCalendar = new \Eluceo\iCal\Component\Calendar('www.onderwijsonline.nl');
        $vCalendar->setPublishedTTL('PT15M');

        if (!is_null($user)) {

            /**
             * Calendar events
             */
            $events = $this->calendarRepository->getEventsForUser($user->id, Carbon::now()->subWeeks(2), Carbon::now()->addWeeks(6));
            foreach ($events as $event) {

                $vEvent = new \Eluceo\iCal\Component\Event();

                $vEvent
                    ->setUseTimezone(true)
                    ->setUseUtc(false)
                    ->setDtStart(Carbon::parse($event['start']))
                    ->setDtEnd(Carbon::parse($event['end']))
                    ->setNoTime(($event['allDay'] == 1 ? true : false))
                    ->setUrl($event['href'])
                    ->setDescription($event['description'])
                    ->setSummary($event['title']);

                $vCalendar->addComponent($vEvent);
            }

            /**
             * Project events
             */
            $events = $this->calendarRepository->getEventsForProjects($user->id, null, null);

            foreach ($events as $event) {
                $vEvent = new \Eluceo\iCal\Component\Event();

                $vEvent
                    ->setUseTimezone(true)
                    ->setUseUtc(false)
                    ->setDtStart(Carbon::parse($event['start']))
                    ->setDtEnd(Carbon::parse($event['end']))
                    ->setNoTime(($event['allDay'] == 1 ? true : false))
                    ->setUrl($event['href'])
                    ->setSummary($event['title']);

                $vCalendar->addComponent($vEvent);
            }

            /**
             * Timetable events
             */
            $events = $this->calendarRepository->getEventsForTimetables($user->id, Carbon::now()->subWeeks(2), Carbon::now()->addWeeks(6));
            foreach ($events as $event) {
                $vEvent = new \Eluceo\iCal\Component\Event();

                $vEvent
                    ->setUseTimezone(true)
                    ->setUseUtc(false)
                    ->setDtStart(Carbon::parse($event['start']))
                    ->setDtEnd(Carbon::parse($event['end']))
                    ->setNoTime(($event['allDay'] == 1 ? true : false))
                    ->setSummary($event['title']);

                $vCalendar->addComponent($vEvent);
            }
        }

        header('Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=onderwijsonline.ics');

        return $vCalendar->render();
    }
```

As I've mentioned above, this exact setup works fine for Google Calendar, but is not for outlook.

Does anyone know why and how that can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a TZID=Europe/Amsterdam but your ics file does not include the VTIMEZONE definition corresponding to this TZID. So before your BEGIN:VEVENT, you should have a BEGIN:VTIMEZONE...END:VTIMEZONE component.

As far as why it still works for Google but not for Outlook: A lot of products do use the Olson TZIDs so they can ignore the fact that the VTIMEZONE definition is missing and just assume that your TZID=Europe/Amsterdam corresponds to their mapping.

Microsoft on the other hand has its own set of TZID identifiers (e.g. "Central Europe Standard Time") and hence can not map your Europe/Amsterdam to a known definition.

Finally, on stack overflow at least your TRANSP, DTEND and URL property do appear on the same line. I'm assuming that this is just a formatting issue when submitting your question (???).